# How can you update a recently added instance of an entity in the same test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit

Here's my problem. I would like to test a function in a controller that implements a simple update.
 I have the error code:

```
The instance of entity type 'Data' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
```

In my case, Data.Id is the primary key.

How can I put the data into the "database" before, without this error occurring?
My assumption is that the data I enter before will be tracked and is in the "tracked state",and therefore no update is possible.

The idea is to test that that everything runs in UpdateData and also performs the update.
The only thing that changes in the new data is for example a new "Data.Title" which is for example a string datatype.

I tryed to change EntityState for the "testData" but this does not help.
I have already searched and tried a lot but I am at a loss.

The error occurs in the UpdateData() function while performing "db.Data.Update(data)".

Here's what I've programmed:

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData(DataDto dataDto){
        var data = mapper.Map<Data>(dataDto);
        //some updating happens here
        db.Data.Update(data);
        wait db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
}
```

HelperFunction:

```
public static ApplicationDbContext DbContext(){
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicaitonDbContext>
           .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
           .Options;

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
        return context;
}
```

TestFunction:

```
[Fact]
public async void UpdateDataTest(){
        //here happens some Mapper initialization
        await using var context = HelperFunction.DbContext();
        await context.Data.AddAsync(testData);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        var dataController = new DataController(context, mapper){};
        var result = await dataController.UpdateData(changedTestData);
        // do some UnitTest

}
```

Comment: Aren't you suppose to mock the dependencies!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya mocking db context can be a fun experience)

Comment: The EF DBContext can be abstracted out in interface and can be injected in controller via DI. Plenty of knowledge available about this on internet.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya but it is not in this particular case.

Comment: I don't see this as a special case or I am missing things by miles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create/recreate new DbContext for `DataController`, something like this:

```
[Fact]
public async void UpdateDataTest(){
        //here happens some Mapper initialization
        var contextId = Guid.NewGuid();
        await using (var context = HelperFunction.DbContext(contextId))
        {
            await context.Data.AddAsync(testData);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        await using var contextForController = HelperFunction.DbContext(contextId);
        var dataController = new DataController(contextForController, mapper){};
        var result = await dataController.UpdateData(changedTestData);
        // do some UnitTest    
}
```

Also you will need to update `HelperFunction.DbContext` so it can accept `Guid` or just some string identifier so it will access the same in-memory database scope:

```
public static ApplicationDbContext DbContext(Guid? guid = null){
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicaitonDbContext>
           .UseInMemoryDatabase((guid ?? Guid.NewGuid()).ToString())
           .Options;

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
        return context;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve it. Than i get the error message "Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store". I am not sure if my questions is clear, i wanted to update the "testData" which in inserted with Data.AddAsync

Comment: Yes, you will need to add optional Guid parameter to `HelperFunction.DbContext`

Comment: @Saboteur see the update (added a new snippet and updated original one).

Comment: I thank you very much for your time and effort. I have implemented everything now but still get the error "Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store".

Now I have checked several times if I have forgotten something you have added :(

Comment: @Saboteur can you please add new code? the error clearly says that you are not getting in-memory databases with the same names(and that was the point of the suggested `HelperFunction.DbContext` change).

Comment: i saw the changes you made to the HelperFunction.DbContext...but still the same error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216093/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-saboteur).